# Can Graphics.DrawImage unintentionally trim an image?

Tags: c#, graphics, tiff

I'm using code that takes a bitmap and converts it to 24 BPP so that I can use it in a program that specifically requires that file format. Here is the code:

```
    using (Bitmap tempImage = new Bitmap(pageToScan.FullPath))
    {
       if (tempImage.PixelFormat != System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
       {
          using (Bitmap tempImage2 = new Bitmap(tempImage.Size.Width, tempImage.Size.Height,
             System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
          {
             using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tempImage2))
             {
                g.DrawImage(tempImage, new Point(0, 0));
             }
             RecognizeBitmap(pageToScan, tempImage2); //Thanks to Tim on this refactoring.
          }
       }
       else
          RecognizeBitmap(pageToScan, tempImage);
    }
```

I have two questions about the code above:

1. With a particular image, I think
   that this clipped the rightmost 200
   pixels right off of tempImage2. Is
   this possible? How might this
   happen, and how can I stop it? A
   friend of mine suggested that it
   might have to do with the stride of
   the TIFF file being used.
2. Is there a
   faster way to convert an image to 24
   BPP in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to use the [Bitmap.Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.clone(VS.80).aspx) method. This takes a PixelFormat as a parameter:

```
using (Bitmap tempImage = new Bitmap(pageToScan.FullPath))    
{           
    if (tempImage.PixelFormat != System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, tempImage.Width, tempImage.Height);
        RecognizeBitmap(pageToScan, tempImage.Clone(r, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);          
    }
    else                  
    {
        RecognizeBitmap(pageToScan, tempImage);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. Should I put a using around tempImage.Clone?

Comment: Yes. You should probably do that and refactor the whole method at the same time to get rid of any leftover duplicated code.